# How to merge two Arrays without loop in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two arrays in Excel VBA:

```
myArr1 = Array("a", "b", "c")
myArr2 = Array("1", "2", "3")
```

Now I want the Array `myArr3`, the dummy code is `myArr3 = myArr1 & myArr2`, so the content of myArr3 is ("a1", "b2", "c3").

Could anyone teach me how to implement this step without Loop functions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoid Loop over Arrays in VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810384/avoid-loop-over-arrays-in-vba)

Comment: The big question is ... why do you need to do it without a loop?

Comment: @YowE3K The reason of “Why I need to do ti without a loop” is : In my opinion, the loop function will cause the poor efficiency, so I need a way to do it directly.

Comment: @GSerg There question named "Avoid Loop over Arrays in VBA? " only has one Array, my question involved two Arrays. So our questions are not the same. Thank you.

Comment: It does not matter how many arrays you have. Please read the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40810594/11683). It applies in full.

Comment: Sure, will do. @GSerg

Answer (score 1):

The following will do it without (explicit) loops, **but it is not a good idea to do it like this**:

```
myArr1 = Array("a", "b", "c")
myArr2 = Array("1", "2", "3")
Range("A1:A3").Value = Application.Transpose(myArr1)
Range("B1:B3").Value = Application.Transpose(myArr2)
Range("C1:C3").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]&RC[-1]"
myArr3 = Application.Transpose(Range("C1:C3").Value)
```

Note: Because of the way they are created, `myArr1` and `myArr2` will be dimensioned `0 To 2`, but `myArr3` will be dimensioned `1 To 3`.

---

A somewhat simpler method that doesn't require loops would be:

```
myArr1 = Array("a", "b", "c")
myArr2 = Array("1", "2", "3")
Dim myArr3(0 To 2)
myArr3(0) = myArr1(0) & myArr2(0)
myArr3(1) = myArr1(1) & myArr2(1)
myArr3(2) = myArr1(2) & myArr2(2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply at first. About method 1, the assisted columns and formula are used, it's low efficiency. About method 2, when I have only 3 elements in the array, this method is doable, but if there are 100,000 elements in my array, should I use this method too? So, I want a way to do that just like myArr1 & myArr2 (EXCEL VBA doesn't support this operation)

Comment: @sniperhgy - Yes, method 1 is low efficiency - I only suggested it because you explicitly stated in your question that you didn't want to use highly-efficient methods such as loops.  And method 2 is unwieldy for large volumes, but loops are what should be used to operate on large volumes if you wish to keep your code manageable.

Comment: About method 1, we reached a consensus, it's low efficiency. But about the efficiency of Loop function, in my opinion, sometimes it's low efficiency too. For example : We want to fill a array into a range, the direct method will be fast, if we use a Loop to do it, we'll cost more time.